# Clone a database with sample data in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want a script that will quickly delete a Test instance of a database and recreate it with only a sample of rows in each table.  I know there is no referential integrity issues or other object restraints such as stored procedures linked to records.  I have tried the following but it states database in use.  I think I am missing something in between the drop and clone.  What am I doing wrong here?  Or does this have to be split between two scripts?

```
-- ensure "master" is selected in SSMS
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='shoesales_TEST')
ALTER DATABASE shoesales_TEST set single_user with rollback immediate
GO
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='shoesales_TEST')
DROP DATABASE shoesales_TEST
GO
DBCC CLONEDATABASE   
(  
    shoesales
    , shoesales_TEST
)
GO
ALTER DATABASE shoesales_TEST SET READ_WRITE
GO
USE shoesales_TEST
GO
INSERT INTO shoesales_TEST.dbo.sizesales
SELECT TOP 30 * FROM shoesales.dbo.sizesales
GO
```

Comment: You script works fine for me (I replaced the initial comment with `use master` and used a small database with logging set to `Simple`). Do you have another tab/connection open somewhere? Double check the current connections with `exec sp_who`.

Comment: @Sander thanks, adding in the USE master helped and I ensured no one else had connected to the database and run the script again